# Ajax POST / GET security

Tags: mysql, ajax, security, post, get

I am building a type of crm using ajax, php and mysql.  I am building the solution with GET and POST requests using ajax xhr requests.  My question is, what is the best way to make sure these requests are secure from any type of hack or attack.  I want to make sure my clients data and this crm is secure.

Right now i am just using long hand ajax/javascript.  I don't use much jquery:  My request looks something like this:

```
 function getContacts()
 {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","xhr_php/getContacts.php",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 var contact = document.getElementById('contact_id').value;
 xmlhttp.send("contact="+contact);
 }
```

my php file looks like this

```
$contact=$_POST['contact'];

$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM contacts 
      WHERE contacts.contact_id = $contact";
```

So this is the basic method i have used to not only retrieve data but also to insert records and run all other queries.  My question is what is the best way to secure these requests and sql queries so that all the data is secure.  I want to make sure this is a secure crm solution so that data can't be corrupted, stolen, injected, hacked, etc.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also just a small addition to Jim's answer (who by the way is 100% correct), I would suggest you look at jquery library, for simple ajax requests (and other cool stuff too)) it is much simpler and quicker to use

Answer (score 4):

This is not secure; it is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack, which has nothing to do with Ajax, POST or GET.  You should not be building SQL statements in that way.  Your question isn't well suited to Stack Overflow - *"How do I make my code secure"* is a vast topic that can't be answered in a simple way.  If you are building this in a professional capacity, please seek out a more senior developer to help you with this - if you are making basic SQL injection mistakes, then it is very unlikely you will be able to build an entire CRM package on your own while making it secure.

Comment: I am fully aware that this is not secure, obviously that is why i am posting. If i thought it was secure i wouldn't be posting the question. Anyhow, i know that i can add mysql_real_escape_string to the variables.  Would this be enough security?  If not, instead of criticizing my lack of knowledge as a beginner can you please post something constructive.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PDO. Following is example code. you can modify it as required.

```
$host  = 'localhost'; 
$dbname = 'contacts';
$username = 'anyuser';
$password = 'your password';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//If contact is int value then pass it through intval function
$contact=intval($_POST['contact']);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacts.contact_id = :contact_id';
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':contact_id', $contact, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
//Use $result is your page
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can do insert / update with PDO as well

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Table  (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

This should be immune to sql injection:

```php
$contact=intval($_POST['contact']);

$sql="SELECT * 
  FROM contacts 
  WHERE contacts.contact_id = $contact";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Fixed,  also my downvote stays because your still totally clueless.

Comment: Think about this,  if that bullshit you posted worked,  why would sql injection exist?  We could just run every query though some function to prevent it.  Although the counter argument would be parametrized queries.

Comment: @user982853  it can if used properly.  But you should use parametrized query library like PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @Rook You're right, I didn't bother looking at what was actually being input. I don't see any way to get anything other than an integer through intval, so that is probably the best way to go here.